# Safe application in Haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, functional-programming, monads

I have a piece of code where inside a list monad, a function is applied. Function may potentially have non-exhaustive pattern matching for its arguments. Therefore when the function is applied, I might get `"Non-exhaustive pattern matching"` error. I would like to turn this error into a monadic fail (in this case, an empty list). In other words I would like to get a similar behavior to what happens when  `Some Pattern Here <- some value` inside a `do` block fails.

**Question**: Is there an *efficient* way to make a function application safe? By efficient I mean something that would be analogous to making the applied function match exhaustively and fail explicitly.

Comment: The question is not clear. Since you are in the list monad why don't you just pattern match within the do-construct or use an explicit case construct otherwise. It's better to post a sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use [spoon](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon) to convert the function from one that throws exceptions into one that returns `Maybe a` values. Then it should be a simple matter of converting `Nothing` to `[]`.

Comment: I'm not sure Spoon should be actively promoted, see this thread http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/acasn/tired_of_functions_that_could_live_in_maybe_but/

Comment: I probably won't risk using it. Anyway, I believe this is the closest one can get to what I asked for.

Comment: I think spoon is fine.  Yeah it breaks theoretical properties and stuff, but the purpose of the library is to deal with crappy code (which has not been defined in a way that plays nice with said theoretical properties anyway).  When the alternative is to re-implement from scratch (or in this case... parse and fix the user's code -- bleh!), spoon is a great alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Hum, maybe with a catch? You should work in the `IO` monad however:

```
import Prelude hiding (catch)
import Control.Monad (MonadPlus, mzero)
import Control.Exception (catch, SomeException)

data B = T | F
    deriving (Show)

f :: B -> B
f T = F

justCatch :: (MonadPlus m) => a -> IO (m a)
justCatch x = catch (x `seq` (return . return) x) handler
  where
    handler :: (MonadPlus m) => SomeException -> IO (m a)
    handler _ = return mzero
```

I'm not sure about possible issues with this solution. At first sight it seems to work, but I would also like to read some opinions from knowledgeable Haskellers. 
I would **not** use this solution for sure in my code: an error should be treated as such, without hiding it.

```
*Main> justCatch $ f T :: IO [B]
[F]
*Main> justCatch $ f F :: IO [B]
[]
*Main> justCatch $ f F :: IO (Maybe B)
Nothing
*Main> justCatch $ f T :: IO (Maybe B)
Just F
*Main> f T
F
*Main> f F
*** Exception: except.hs:8:1-7: Non-exhaustive patterns in function Main.f
```

Comment: `IO` monad is not an option. I try to keep my code as pure as possible.

Comment: At the best of my knowledge you only can use `catch` to handle exceptions like that one (which forces you to work in IO). If you don't want to use spoon (that uses unsafe operations) proposed by Daniel, I'm afraid you might not have any other options.

Comment: Okay, a negative answer is still an answer. Thanks.